# mongoosastic search with two fields with and condition

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I have a chatting applications developed in Angular js, Node.js, MongoDB with elastic search integration. I had provided search functionality for chats, which user can enter any combination. Options are chat message, user and date.

So i want to search in elastic search db with help of nodejs, with mutiple field combination. For example, 1) search with username='mohan' and the date='anydate', 2) username='mohan' and chatmessage='Hi there'.

So the result should come which satisfy both conditions.

How can we achieve this using mongoosastic? I tried with below query. But it is giving result with OR condition, I want with AND condition.

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "should": [{
                "match": {
                    "feedMsg": "Hi there"
                }
            }, {
                "match": {
                    "userId": 'mohan'
                }
            }, {
                "range": {
                    "feedTime": {
                        "from": '27/10/2016',
                        "to": '27/10/2016'
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solutions. Bool Query with must is working for me.

```
{
   "bool" : {
      "must" :     [],
      "should" :   [],
      "must_not" : [],
      "filter":    []
   }
}
```

1. must- All of these clauses must match. The equivalent of AND.
2. must_not - All of these clauses must not match. The equivalent of
       NOT.
3. should - At least one of these clauses must match. The equivalent of OR.
4. filter - Clauses that must match, but are run in non-scoring,
   filtering mode.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this format, it really works...

```
 var query = {
    query_string: {
      filtered: {
        query: {
          multi_match: {
            query: req.query.q, // or anything you will put here
          }
        },
        filter: {
          term: {
            'field': value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```